# getting frequency count of the values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
               one  two three   four    five    six
Date                        
2011-01-10  D   DD  DDU DDUD    DDUDU   DDUDUU
2011-01-11  U   UD  UDD UDDU    UDDUD   UDDUDU
2011-01-12  U   UU  UUD UUDD    UUDDU   UUDDUD
2011-01-13  D   DU  DUU DUUD    DUUDD   DUUDDU
2011-01-14  U   UD  UDU UDUU    UDUUD   UDUUDD
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2023-12-28  U   UU  UUU UUUU    UUUUD   UUUUDU
2023-12-29  D   DU  DUU DUUU    DUUUU   DUUUUD
2024-01-02  U   UD  UDU UDUU    UDUUU   UDUUUU
2024-01-03  D   DU  DUD DUDU    DUDUU   DUDUUU
2024-01-04  U   UD  UDU UDUD    UDUDU   UDUDUU
3182 rows × 6 columns
```

i wanted to get the frequency counts of the unique values of the column two.
i used the following code

````
```
two = pd.DataFrame(df['two'].value_counts())
two['total'] = two['count'].sum()
two['win%'] = (100 * two['count'] / two['count'].sum()).round(2) 

```
````

the output is

```
       count    total   win%
two         
UU  771 2429    31.74
DD  556 2429    22.89
DU  551 2429    22.68
UD  551 2429    22.68
```

why i am getting UD and DU as same frequency.. ??

first i thought it is a coincidence. then i changed the original dataframe. the results are always same.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to calculate the proportions without going through the column with the total sum.

```
import pandas as pd

# Calculate counts and percentages
counts = df['two'].value_counts()
percentages = df['two'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

# Creating a new DataFrame with counts and percentages
two = pd.DataFrame({'Count': counts, 'Percentage': percentages})
```

This will give you a `DataFrame` with both counts and percentages, simplifying your original process. Additionally, it might also help clarify if the issue with `'UD'` and `'DU'` is indeed a data-related anomaly or just a coincidence.

**Edit**: Alternatively use the following:

```
counts = df.groupby('two').size()
percentages = (counts / counts.sum()) * 100
two = pd.DataFrame({'Count': counts, 'Percentage': percentages})
```

Comment: tried that. still both DU and UD showing same frequency. the method pd.value_counts() considers DU and UD as same..

Comment: @noobmaster69 I modified my answer with another approach. Please first run `df['two'] = df['two'].astype(str)` and then the alternative approach.

Comment: @noobmaster69 Have you tried forcing the conversion to string and the alternative approach?

Comment: yes. the result is same.. i think the problem is with the df.value_counts method..

Comment: @noobmaster69 Can you please provide the full code of a reproducible example, please?